# I have a CEdit box. When I disable the box and immediately after try to call SetReadOnly, it stays disabled. Why is this?

Tags: c++, mfc

There's not a particular reason I'm wanting to do this, it's more for my knowledge of how this stuff works.

I have an edit box derived from CWnd. Let's call it m_edtBox.
When I call `m_edtBox.EnableWindow(FALSE)`

followed immediately by

`m_edtBox.SetReadOnly(TRUE)`,

the box stays disabled. It does not take on the read-only property. I'm simply curious as to why this is?

Comment: Why would you expect that changing whether or not a edit box is read-only would change whether it is enabled/disabled? I would expect those two things to be orthogonal.

Comment: I would imagine it's disabled and read-only. I can't see why this behavior surprises you.

Comment: @Jesper Disabled disables the controls as well (like a scroll bar), and when I call SetReadOnly directly after, the controls remain disabled. So it seems like SetReadOnly has no effect, and doesn't "override" anything. My understanding of mfc is very naive, so I'm trying to make sense of this. I guess it's my way of trying to make sure they're completely exclusive.

Comment: With read-only you still can set the cursor and select text. With "disabled" you can do nothing.

Comment: @JimmyBlundell `EnableWindow` and `SetReadOnly`  are two different totally unrelated things. Once a window has bveen disabled via `EnableWindow(FALSE)`, it stays disabled until you call `EnableWindow(TRUE)`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I thought so, I guess for some odd reason I wanted to make sure. I got it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A [disabled window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#disabled-windows) is a window that

> receives no keyboard or mouse input from the user [...].

In other words, the [WS_DISABLED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles) window style controls, whether a control gets to handle user input at all.

Contrast that with the [ES_READONLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/edit-control-styles) edit control style. It controls which user input that has an effect on the control.

> Prevents the user from typing or editing text in the edit control.

Both styles can be set independently, and although both relate to user input, they serve different purposes.